# Selenium/python: extract text from a dynamically-loading webpage after every scroll

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium/python to automatically scroll down a social media website and scrape posts. I'm currently extracting all the text in one "hit" *after* scrolling a certain number of times (code below), but instead I want to extract just the newly-loaded text after each scroll.

For example, if the page initially contained the text "A, B, C", then after the first scroll it displayed "D, E, F", I'd want to store "A, B, C", then scroll, then store "D, E, F" etc.

The specific items I'm wanting to extract are the dates of the posts and the message text, which can be obtained with the css selectors `'.message-date'` and `'.message-body'`, respectively (e.g., `dates = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.message-date')`).

**Can anyone advise on how to extract just the newly-loaded text after each scroll?**

Here's my current code (which extracts all the dates/messages *after* I finish scrolling):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#load website to scrape
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://stocktwits.com/symbol/USDJPY?q=%24USDjpy")

#Scroll the webpage
ScrollNumber=3 #max scrolls
print(str(ScrollNumber)+ " scrolldown will be done.")
for i in range(1,ScrollNumber):  #scroll down X times
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3) #Delay between 2 scrolls down to be sure the page loaded
    ## I WANT TO SAVE/STORE ANY NEWLY LOADED POSTS HERE RATHER 
    ## THAN EXTRACTING IT ALL IN ONE GO AT THE END OF THE LOOP

# Extract messages and dates.
## I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS DATA ON THE FLY IN THE ABOVE
## LOOP RATHER THAN EXTRACTING IT HERE
dates = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.message-date')
messages = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.message-body')
```

Comment: Why all this hassle when it uses API in background? `https://stocktwits.com/streams/poll?stream=symbol&max=92297722&stream_id=674&substream=top&item_id=674`

Comment: Thanks for the info, but would you mind elaborating on how I can use the API to download data? That URL doesn't work for me. Regarding why I didn't use the API in the first place, a) I couldn't figure out how to do this (I'm a newbie with APIs) and b) I heard that the API could only be used to download the data for the last 30 days, whereas I need at least a year of posts.

Comment: You need to learn how to use Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to look for network requests. You may retrieve the page first and then figure out the API url from the page. The thing is that if the page scrolling adds new data, it would always add it by making a call to API which would either return JSON or HTML or data in some other format. So if you can get year data manually using scrolling, you can get it through API also. That is because even the webpage has to fetch the data to show you

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the number of messages in a variable and use `xpath` and `position()` to get the newly added posts

```
dates = []
messages = []
num_of_posts = 1
for i in range(1, ScrollNumber):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    dates.extend(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//div[@class="message-date"])[position()>=' + str(num_of_posts) + ']'))
    messages.extend(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//div[contains(@class, "message-body")])[position()>=' + str(num_of_posts) + ']'))
    num_of_posts = len(dates)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with facebook posts.
For that I save the post ID (or whatever value that's unique for the post, even a Hash) in a List and then when you made the query again, you need to check if that ID is in your list or not.

Also, you can remove the DOM that is parsed, so only the new ones will exists.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, if you can do what you need to do via hitting the API directly, thats your best bet. If you absolutely must use Selenium, see my solution below.

I do something similar to the below for my needs.

- I'm leveraging `:nth-child()` aspect of CSS paths to individually find elements as they load.
- I'm also using selenium's explicit wait functionality (via the `explicit` package, `pip install explicit`) to efficiently wait for elements to load.

The script is quit fast (no calls to sleep()), however, the webpage itself has so much junk going on in the background that it often takes a while for selenium to return control to the script.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from itertools import count
import sys
import time

from explicit import waiter, CSS
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait as Wait


# The CSS selectors we will use
POSTS_BASE_CSS = 'ol.stream-list > li'              # All li elements
POST_BASE_CSS = POSTS_BASE_CSS + ":nth-child({0})"  # li child element at index {0}
POST_DATE_CSS = POST_BASE_CSS + ' div.message-date'     # li child element at {0} with div.message-date
POST_BODY_CSS = POST_BASE_CSS + ' div.message-body'     # li child element at {0} with div.message-date



class Post(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, post_index):
        self.driver = driver
        self.date_css = POST_DATE_CSS.format(post_index)
        self.text_css = POST_BODY_CSS.format(post_index)

    @property
    def date(self):
        return waiter.find_element(self.driver, self.date_css, CSS).text

    @property
    def text(self):
        return waiter.find_element(self.driver, self.text_css, CSS).text


def get_posts(driver, url, max_screen_scrolls):
    """ Post object generator """
    driver.get(url)
    screen_scroll_count = 0

    # Wait for the initial posts to load:
    waiter.find_elements(driver, POSTS_BASE_CSS, CSS)

    for index in count(1):
        # Evaluate if we need to scroll the screen, or exit the generator
        # If there is no element at this index, it means we need to scroll the screen
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('ol.stream-list > :nth-child({0})'.format(index))) == 0:
            if screen_scroll_count >= max_screen_scrolls:
                # Break if we have already done the max scrolls
                break

            # Get count of total posts on page
            post_count = len(waiter.find_elements(driver, POSTS_BASE_CSS, CSS))

            # Scroll down
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            screen_scroll_count += 1

            def posts_load(driver):
                """ Custom explicit wait function; waits for more posts to load in """
                return len(waiter.find_elements(driver, POSTS_BASE_CSS, CSS)) > post_count

            # Wait until new posts load in
            Wait(driver, 20).until(posts_load)

        # The list elements have sponsored ads and scripts mixed in with the posts we
        # want to scrape. Check if they have a div.message-date element and continue on
        # if not
        includes_date_css = POST_DATE_CSS.format(index)
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(includes_date_css)) == 0:
            continue

        yield Post(driver, index)


def main():
    url = "https://stocktwits.com/symbol/USDJPY?q=%24USDjpy"
    max_screen_scrolls = 4
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        for post_num, post in enumerate(get_posts(driver, url, max_screen_scrolls), 1):
            print("*" * 40)
            print("Post #{0}".format(post_num))
            print("\nDate: {0}".format(post.date))
            print("Text: {0}\n".format(post.text[:34]))

    finally:
        driver.quit()  # Use try/finally to make sure the driver is closed


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Full disclosure:
I'm the creator of the `explicit` package. You could easily rewrite the above using explicit waits directly, at the expense of readability.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I gave the Bounty to another user as he answered the question first, but your code works great too.

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you want. But, I wouldn't scrape the site this way...it'll just get slower and slower the longer it runs. RAM usage will spiral out of control too.

```
import time
from hashlib import md5

import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = 'https://stocktwits.com/symbol/USDJPY?q=%24USDjpy'
CSS = By.CSS_SELECTOR

driver.get(URL)


def scrape_for(max_seconds=300):
    found = set()
    end_at = time.time() + max_seconds
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.5)

    while True:
        # find elements
        elms = driver.find_elements(CSS, 'li.messageli')

        for li in elms:
            # get the information we need about each post
            text = li.find_element(CSS, 'div.message-content')
            key = md5(text.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')).hexdigest()

            if key in found:
                continue

            found.add(key)

            try:
                date = li.find_element(CSS, 'div.message-date').text
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                date = None

            yield text.text, date

        if time.time() > end_at:
            raise StopIteration

        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(
                       (CSS, 'div#more-button-loading')))

    raise StopIteration


for twit in scrape_for(60):
    print(twit)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really what you asked for (it isn't a selenium solution), it's actually a solution using the API that the page is using in the background. Using selenium instead of the API is an overkill in my opinion.

Here a script using the API:

```
import re

import requests

STREAM_ID_REGEX = re.compile(r"data-stream='symbol-(?P<id>\d+)'")
CSRF_TOKEN_REGEX = re.compile(r'<meta name="csrf-token" content="(?P<csrf>[^"]+)" />')

URL = 'https://stocktwits.com/symbol/USDJPY?q=%24USDjpy'
API_URL = 'https://stocktwits.com/streams/poll?stream=symbol&substream=top&stream_id={stream_id}&item_id={stream_id}'


def get_necessary_info():
    res = requests.get(URL)

    # Extract stream_id
    match = STREAM_ID_REGEX.search(res.text)
    stream_id = match.group('id')

    # Extract CSRF token
    match = CSRF_TOKEN_REGEX.search(res.text)
    csrf_token = match.group('csrf')

    return stream_id, csrf_token


def get_messages(stream_id, csrf_token, max_messages=100):
    base_url = API_URL.format(stream_id=stream_id)

    # Required headers
    headers = {
        'x-csrf-token': csrf_token,
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }

    messages = []
    more = True
    max_value = None
    while more:
        # Pagination
        if max_value:
            url = '{}&max={}'.format(base_url, max_value)
        else:
            url = base_url

        # Get JSON response
        res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = res.json()

        # Add returned messages
        messages.extend(data['messages'])

        # Check if there are more messages
        more = data['more']
        if more:
            max_value = data['max']

        # Check if we have enough messages
        if len(messages) >= max_messages:
            break

    return messages


def main():
    stream_id, csrf_token = get_necessary_info()
    messages = get_messages(stream_id, csrf_token)

    for message in messages:
        print(message['created_at'], message['body'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the first lines of the output:

```
Tue, 03 Oct 2017 03:54:29 -0000 $USDJPY (113.170) Daily Signal remains LONG from 109.600 on 12/09. SAR point now at 112.430. website for details
Tue, 03 Oct 2017 03:33:02 -0000 JPY: Selling JPY Via Long $USDJPY Or Long $CADJPY Still Attractive  - SocGen https://www.efxnews.com/story/37129/jpy-selling-jpy-long-usdjpy-or-long-cadjpy-still-attractive-socgen#.WdMEqnCGMCc.twitter
Tue, 03 Oct 2017 01:05:06 -0000 $USDJPY buy signal on 03 OCT 2017 01:00 AM UTC by AdMACD Trading System (Timeframe=H1) http://www.cosmos4u.net/index.php/forex/usdjpy/usdjpy-buy-signal-03-oct-2017-01-00-am-utc-by-admacd-trading-system-timeframe-h1 #USDJPY #Forex
Tue, 03 Oct 2017 00:48:46 -0000 $EURUSD nice H&S to take price lower on $USDJPY just waiting 4 inner trendline to break. built up a lot of strength
Tue, 03 Oct 2017 00:17:13 -0000 $USDJPY The Instrument reached the 100% from lows at 113.25 and sold in 3 waves, still can see 114.14 area.#elliottwave $USDX
...
```

Comment: @jruf003 could you let me know what the problem is with my answer?

Comment: I assume you're referring to being down-voted? Presumably this is because your post didn't directly answer my question, but I'm not the one who down-voted you. In fact, I've up-voted you because you read between the lines and gave me a great solution (thanks).

Answer (score -3):

Just do sleep after scrolling , be sure to work with selenium as like as real machine its necessary to wait till page load new content . 
I recommend you  to do it with wait function in selenium or just easily add sleep function in your code  to load the contents .

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I'm already using `time.sleep()` in the example code I provided - are you suggesting I can use this function in a different way to solve my specific problem (which is to extract only newly-loaded posts after each scroll as per the example in the second paragraph of my original question)? If so, could you please elaborate on how this can be achieved?

Comment: AND it's important to use python ?

Comment: Dear friend , I understand the issue let I check it out that page with php .. I will tell you in next day

Comment: That would be great, thanks. I'm only familiar with R and Python but will use whatever language works.

Comment: did you ever check this out with php as discussed above @kiamoz?

Comment: not yet but I'll do it in next days.. I'm sure that will be work via php

Comment: Dear sir , I did it  with selenium ! are you need help yet ?

Comment: Hi kiamoz. Thanks but I managed to get a solution via the answer I accepted above